# Click a dropdown using Selenium in Python Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, selenium, button, jupyter-notebook, dropdown

How can I click a button with the below HTML? When clicking the button it provides a dropdown and multiple options (but below you can see it only shows "all registries").

I tried with no luck many versions of:
driver.find_element_by_id() and
driver.find_element_by_class_name()

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can click on `all registries` with the below code  :

**xpath :**

```
//strong[text()='all registries']/../../..
```

use it in code like this :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//strong[text()='all registries']/../../.."))).click()
```

**Imports  :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```